# BackgroundWorker, can't send other variable other than numeric values to the function callback

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, backgroundworker

Background worker, passing variables are not working, in my example I explain everything, I put only the functions that were important, I have the other functions from the BackgroundWorker.

```
int TheFunction(unordered_map<std::string,std::string> options, BackgroundWorker^ worker, DoWorkEventArgs ^ e){

    if(options["option1"].compare("options") == 0){
            //...
        }

        return 0;
}

    void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(Object^ sender, DoWorkEventArgs^ e ){
         BackgroundWorker^ worker = dynamic_cast<BackgroundWorker^>(sender);     
        //e->Result = TheFunction( safe_cast<Int32>(e->Argument), worker, e ); //That's how I do to send an integer value and works just fine, but I don't know how to send non-numeric values with safe_cast or something that works, in the function it looks like this: TheFunction(int index, ...) it works fine, I want to know with unordered_map or with strings also would work, I want more than one argument if you can do with std::string
          e->Result = TheFunction(safe_cast<unordered_map<std::string,std::string>>(e->Argument)); //I tried this, and it didn't work

    }


void CallBackgroundWorker(){
         this->backgroundWorker2 = gcnew System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker;
         this->backgroundWorker2->WorkerReportsProgress = true;
         this->backgroundWorker2->WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
         this->backgroundWorker2->DoWork += gcnew DoWorkEventHandler( this, &GUISystem::backgroundWorker2_DoWork );
         this->backgroundWorker2->RunWorkerCompleted += gcnew RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler( this, &GUISystem::backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted );
         this->backgroundWorker2->ProgressChanged += gcnew ProgressChangedEventHandler( this, &GUISystem::backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged );


         unordered_map<std::string,std::string>* options = unordered_map<std::string,std::string>();
         options["option1"] = "valor1";
         options["option2"] = "valor2";

         this->backgroundWorker2->RunWorkerAsync(options);
}
```

So how do I do to send the unordered_map or a std::string (more than 1 arguments) ?

thanks in advance. that would help a lot.

Comment: The RunWorkerAsync() method requires an argument that derives from Object.  That doesn't work for a native C++ class like unordered_map, they don't derive from Object.  You'll need to create a wee little helper ref class that just stores the pointer and pass an instance of it instead.

Comment: Oh, and be careful with pointers, they still need to be valid by the time the worker thread starts running.

Comment: how could I do that ? I was thinking about using fieldGetter and fieldSetter but I don't know how to use it, I searched how to do it but no success. I'm not even sure if I can do this, I wanted to be able to pass two strings, is that possible? could I have a suggestion in example? thanks!

Comment: oh and could you show me how do I create this wee little helper? :D Make it as an answer so I can set as "correct answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
unordered_map<std::string,std::string>* options = unordered_map<std::string,std::string>();
```

isn't legal even in standard C++.  A pointer needs to store an address, not an object.  So probably you meant to say `new` to use dynamic allocation (after all, the object needs to survive until the callback runs on the other thread).

At that point, you can wrap the pointer inside `System::IntPtr`, and in the callback, cast the result of `ToPointer()`.